# Neither recordset or SP approach to validating salted hashbyte fields working

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, vbscript, asp-classic

**UPDATE**: ASP page still always returns a "1", even when correct password is supplied, but when stored proc is run in SSMS, it works properly.

I added SELECT statements for the fields being tested and modified the running of the stored proc to return a recordset when executing the command.

```
Set rs2 = cmd1.Execute
Response.Write "rs2.PWord = " & "" & rs2(0) & "<br />"
Response.Write "rs2.PWordIN = " & "" & rs2(1) & "<br />"
Response.Write "rs2.ReturnVal = " & "" & rs2(2) & "<br />"
Response.Write "rs2.PWordWSalt = " & "" & rs2(3) & "<br />"
```

All data is returned correctly - but the return value stubbornly is always '1', until I run it inside SSMS. Why?

The account running the stored proc has sufficient privileges. Is there something specific, account or user-rights-wise, that I should be checking?

Also, the actual connection provider is MSDASQL.1.

**ORIGINAL POST**: 
I have a stored procedure that works perfectly. The goal is to compare a salt + password stored in a table against the same salt + a user-supplied password. If the comparison matches, the password is good; otherwise it is not.

Problem is when I run the SP within a classic ASP/VBScript page. The record set's two fields return empty, so the compare is always 'true'.

```
Select toPWord, toPWordSalt, master.dbo.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HashBytes('SHA1', toPWordSalt+toPWord), 1, 0) as HashByteValue, master.dbo.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HashBytes('SHA1', toPWordSalt+'" & trim(vLogOnPWord) & "'), 1, 0) as HashByteValueCOMP from toUSERS_WORKAREAe"
```

where: topWordSalt is the stored salt used; toPWord is the stored password for the user; vLogOnPWord is the user-supplied password from the ASP/VBScript UI.

Originally I tried CONVERT, then switched to varbintohexsubstring. Either one returns an empty field in the recordset:

```
SQLS1 = "Select toPWord, toPWordSalt, master.dbo.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HashBytes('SHA1', toPWordSalt+toPWord), 1, 0) as HashByteValue, master.dbo.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HashBytes('SHA1', toPWordSalt+'" & trim(vLogOnPWord) & "'), 1, 0) as HashByteValueCOMP from toUSERS_WORKAREAe" 

rs2.Open SQLS1, xConn, adOpenStatic
vPWordTest = "" & rs2("toPWord")
vHashByteValue = "" & rs2("Hashbytevalue")
vHashByteValue_COMP = "" & rs2("HashbytevalueCOMP")
if IsEmpty(vHashByteValue) then
   Response.Write "vHashByteValue is empty<br />"
end if
```

As a simple query test, in SSMS, the above query does return fields fine:

[recordset results in SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFF2K.jpg)

Alternatively, I have written an SP, "Verify_Hash", which writes a "0" if the hashbytes match, and "1" if they do not. Again, executing this SP within SSMS works perfectly. But called from ASP/VBScript it always fails (the flag is set to equal '1', instead of '0', when the hashbyte fields DO match).

```
USE [10734]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_VerifyHash]    Script Date: 12/28/2017 11:50:41 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_VerifyHash]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@toPWordIN varchar(20), 
@toPHashErr int OUTPUT 
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;


declare @toHashByteValue varchar(120)
declare @toHashByteValueTEST varchar(120)
declare @toPWord varchar(20)
declare @toPSalt varchar(120)
declare @toPHash varchar(120)
declare @toPHashOut varchar(120)

Set @toPWord = (select toPWord from toUSERS_WORKAREAe)
Set @toPSalt = (select toPWordSalt from toUSERS_WORKAREAe)
Set @toPHash = (select hashbytes('SHA1', @toPSalt+@toPWord) as Hashbytevalue from toUSERS_WORKAREAe)
Set @toPHashOut = (select hashbytes('SHA1', @toPSalt+@toPWordIN) as HashbyteValueTEST from toUSERS_WORKAREAe)

if (@toPHash = @toPHashOut)
BEGIN
   -- PRINT 'YES'
   SET @toPHashErr = '0'
   UPDATE toUSERS_WORKAREAe SET toPHashErr = '0';
   END
else
   BEGIN
   -- PRINT 'NO'
  SET @toPHashErr = '1'
  UPDATE toUSERS_WORKAREAe SET toPHashErr = '1';
  END
END
```

This password compare logic is by no means complete. Goal is to actually compare the AES-256 encrypted key, and not the plain text version. My plan is to use that symmetric key result value, and not plain text. However, as my first step I endeavored to create the SP and VBScript code to process the logic, and I cannot get the basics to work.

```
SET cmd1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command") 
SET cmd1.ActiveConnection = xConn
cmd1.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd1.CommandText = "sp_VerifyHash"
cmd1.Parameters.Append cmd1.CreateParameter("@toPwordIN", adVarChar, 1, 20, vExistingPWord) '// adParamInput
cmd1.Parameters.Append cmd1.CreateParameter("@toPHashErr", adInteger, 4, 1)                 '// adParamReturnValue
cmd1.Execute
cmd1.Close
RETVAL = cmd1("@toPHashErr")
Response.Write "@toPHashErr = " & nRETVAL & "<br />"
Response.Write "@toPwdCheckOUT  = " & cmd("@toPwdCheckOUT") & "<br />"
Response.Write "@toHashCheckOUT = " & cmd("@toHashCheckOUT") & "<br />"
```

Lastly, the connection strings are:

```
Driver={SQL Server}; Server=WIN-XX0YYZZ8YYY; Database=databasename; Trusted_Connection=yes;

Set xConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
```

I would be happy with either the field comparison test working (with the recordset approach), OR, the stored procedure posting through the ASP page the correct "0" or "1" value, so VB-Script can then read it. I have spent many hours going through many, many of your related posts and have yet to come across a solution to either (or both) issues. Any help you can provide would be more than appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you could end your stored proc with select you could end your stored procedure with `select @toPHashErr as result` and read the resulting recordset in asp

Comment: Hi schudel - I added a return value, and ... it worked! Odd that when returning the value it somehow a) didn't return the correct value in the variable and b) somehow prevented the stored proc from running at all. The code will undergo further testing to make sure this fix is not a fluke, but so far, 'confidence is high'. Thank you!

Comment: Hold the press. I was incorrect. Today I tried with another user account and the same thing is happening. While in SSMS right-mouse clicking and choosing "Run Stored Procedure ... " works, running the same SP from ASP does not. It always returns a "1" for a return value.

Comment: how many rows are there in toUSERS_WORKAREAe?